# React getting Invalid state while using async action creator with redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my app component i have list of posts that contains user id, i want to display the user name and details against that user id, here's my app component's jsx:

> App Component JSX:

```
render() {
    const posts = [...someListOfPosts];
    return posts.map((post) => {
        return (
            <div className="item" key={post.id}>
                <div className="content">
                    <User userId={post.userId} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

> User Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser } from '../actions';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser(this.props.userId); // getting correct userId
    }

    render() {
        const { user } = this.props;
        // Not displaying correct user i.e. showing the last resolved user for each post
        return (
            <div>
                {user && <div className="header">{user.name}</div>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        user: state.user
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUser })(UserHeader);
```

I'm getting correct props for userId but for every post it displays the last resolved user from the api. It should be relevant user for every post.

> Reducer and Action Creator

```
// action

export const fetchUser = (id) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`);
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_USER',
            payload: (response.status === 200 && response.data) ? response.data : null; // it returns single user not array of user
        });
    }
}

// reducer

export default (state = null, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_USER':
            return action.payload; // i know it can be fixed by defaulting state to empty array and returning like so [...state, action.payload] but why should i return complete state why not just a single user object here?
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The fetchUser action creator returns single payload of a user not an array then why it's required to return the state like `[...state, action.payload]` why can't it be done by returning `action.payload` only? I've tried it by returning only `action.payload` but in my user component it displays the last resolved user from the api every time for each post. I'm confused regarding this.

Comment: you're defaulting initial state to null - default it to empty array

Comment: I need to understand this that why i need to return an array for this from the reducer? why can't it be done by single object that is returned from the api?

Comment: you need to keep your return values consistent and predictable.  if you return an object instead of an array randomly, somewhere you'll be using `array.pop()` or something and get an error and wonder what's going on

Comment: i got your point for defaulting initial state to empty array, but the question is the fetchUser action creator return single payload of a user not an array then why it's required to return the state like `[...state, action.payload];` why can't it be done by returning `action.payload` only? I've tried it by returning only `action.payload` but in my user component it displays the last resolved user from the api every time for each post. I'm confused regarding this.

Comment: "why i need to return the complete array" because you are doing this - `state.user.find(user => user.id === props.userId)` which is for an array

Comment: @Deryck can you please go through my question again as my issue is with the persistence of the user component not the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to the store using mapStateToProps which rerenders when ever there is a change in the store. As you are trying to render via props in User component, the application retains the last value of user and re-renders all the old User Components as well. If you want to ignore the props updates make the result local to the component.

You can possibly try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser } from '../actions';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
userDetails:{}
}
}

    componentDidMount() {
fetch(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${this.props.userId})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            userDetails: result.data
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: false
          });
        }
      )

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.userDetails && <div className="header">{this.state.userDetails.name}</div>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {

    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUser })(UserHeader);
```